# Getting a nested object in powershell with a JSON return

Tags: json, powershell

I'm currently trying to retrieve information from a Hyper-V server through a Powershell REST server. Currently, I have an HTTP-Listener set up in powershell to receive a command, run it, and return the results in JSON.

If I send the command:
localhost:8888?command=get-vm -ComputerName ServerName

I get a very LOOOONG list of machines and parameters that I just really don't need.

```
{
    "Id": "cd12132a-424d-4a90-9be2-cc521c5cdf8a",
    "Name": "3Y6S9438",
    "State": 2,
    "IntegrationServicesState": "Up to date",
    "OperationalStatus": [
      2
    ],
    "PrimaryOperationalStatus": 2,
    "SecondaryOperationalStatus": null,
    "StatusDescriptions": [
      "Operating normally"
    ],
    "PrimaryStatusDescription": "Operating normally",
    "SecondaryStatusDescription": null,
    "Status": "Operating normally",
    "Heartbeat": 5,
    "ReplicationState": 0,
    "ReplicationHealth": 0,
    "ReplicationMode": 0,
    "CPUUsage": 0,
    "MemoryAssigned": 2147483648,
    "MemoryDemand": 0,
    "MemoryStatus": "",
    "SmartPagingFileInUse": false,
    "Uptime": {
      "Ticks": 9672280000000,
      "Days": 11,
      "Hours": 4,
      "Milliseconds": 0,
      "Minutes": 40,
      "Seconds": 28,
      "TotalDays": 11.194768518518519,
      "TotalHours": 268.6744444444444,
      "TotalMilliseconds": 967228000,
      "TotalMinutes": 16120.466666666667,
      "TotalSeconds": 967228
    },
    "IntegrationServicesVersion": {
      "Major": 6,
      "Minor": 3,
      "Build": 9600,
      "Revision": 17831,
      "MajorRevision": 0,
      "MinorRevision": 17831
    },
    "ResourceMeteringEnabled": false,
    "ConfigurationLocation": "C:\\ClusterStorage\\Volume1\\3Y6S9438\\3Y6S9438",
    "SnapshotFileLocation": "C:\\ClusterStorage\\Volume1\\3Y6S9438\\3Y6S9438\\",
    "AutomaticStartAction": 2,
    "AutomaticStopAction": 4,
    "AutomaticStartDelay": 0,
    "SmartPagingFilePath": "C:\\ClusterStorage\\Volume1\\3Y6S9438\\3Y6S9438\\",
    "NumaAligned": true,
    "NumaNodesCount": 1,
    "NumaSocketCount": 1,
    "Key": {
      "Id": "cd12132a-424d-4a90-9be2-cc521c5cdf8a"
    },
    "IsDeleted": false,
    "ComputerName": "AB124322",
    "Version": "5.0",
    "Notes": "#CLUSTER-INVARIANT#:{f5f3cfe0-28e7-479a-a39d-679975bcd81f}",
    "Generation": 1,
    "Path": "C:\\ClusterStorage\\Volume1\\3Y6S9438\\3Y6S9438",
    "CreationTime": "/Date(1466293818382)/",
    "IsClustered": true,
    "SizeOfSystemFiles": 55480,
    "ParentSnapshotId": null,
    "ParentSnapshotName": null,
    "MemoryStartup": 2147483648,
    "DynamicMemoryEnabled": false,
    "MemoryMinimum": 536870912,
    "MemoryMaximum": 4294967296,
    "ProcessorCount": 2,
    "RemoteFxAdapter": null,
    "NetworkAdapters": [
      "Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.VMNetworkAdapter"
    ],
    "FibreChannelHostBusAdapters": [],
    "ComPort1": {
      "Path": "",
      "ComputerName": "AB124322",
      "Name": "COM 1",
      "Id": "Microsoft:CD12132A-424D-4A90-9BE2-CC521C5CDF8A\\8E3A359F-559A-4B6A-98A9-1690A6100ED7\\0",
      "IsDeleted": false,
      "VMId": "cd12132a-424d-4a90-9be2-cc521c5cdf8a",
      "VMName": "3Y6S9438",
      "VMSnapshotId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "VMSnapshotName": null,
      "Key": null
    },
    "ComPort2": {
      "Path": "",
      "ComputerName": "AB124322",
      "Name": "COM 2",
      "Id": "Microsoft:CD12132A-424D-4A90-9BE2-CC521C5CDF8A\\8E3A359F-559A-4B6A-98A9-1690A6100ED7\\1",
      "IsDeleted": false,
      "VMId": "cd12132a-424d-4a90-9be2-cc521c5cdf8a",
      "VMName": "3Y6S9438",
      "VMSnapshotId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "VMSnapshotName": null,
      "Key": null
    },
    "FloppyDrive": {
      "PoolName": null,
      "Path": null,
      "Disk": null,
      "ComputerName": "AB124322",
      "Name": "Diskette Drive",
      "Id": "Microsoft:CD12132A-424D-4A90-9BE2-CC521C5CDF8A\\8F0D2762-0B00-4E04-AF4F-19010527CB93\\0\\0\\D",
      "IsDeleted": false,
      "VMId": "cd12132a-424d-4a90-9be2-cc521c5cdf8a",
      "VMName": "3Y6S9438",
      "VMSnapshotId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "VMSnapshotName": null,
      "Key": null
    },
    "DVDDrives": [
      "Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.DvdDrive"
    ],
    "HardDrives": [
      "Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.HardDiskDrive"
    ],
    "VMIntegrationService": [
      "Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.VMIntegrationComponent",
      "Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.VMIntegrationComponent",
      "Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.DataExchangeComponent",
      "Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.ShutdownComponent",
      "Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.VMIntegrationComponent",
      "Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.GuestServiceInterfaceComponent"
    ],
    "VMName": "3Y6S9438",
    "VMId": "cd12132a-424d-4a90-9be2-cc521c5cdf8a"
  },
```

And since there are multiple results returned (not shown), I don't get any information on say the NetworkAdapters array or the HardDrives

So, I know I don't want ALL those attributes. So I can just narrow it down with a Select

```
Get-VM | Select Id, Name, NetworkAdapters, HardDrives, etc...
```

But I still run into the same issue if there are multiple results returned. I don't get any info on those arrays for HardDrives or NetworkAdapters.

I read into using ExpandProperty, but I run into this issue:

```
select : The property cannot be processed because the property "Id" already exists.
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Also, I don't need all 56 attributes from a Network object as well. Can I run a select on the network query as well to narrow it all down?

Thanks

EDIT:

Example of a command that results in an error

```
get-vm -ComputerName AB124322 | select name, id, state -ExpandProperty networkadapters
```

to which I get this error

```
The property cannot be processed because the property "Name" already exists.
```

Comment: I had no issues with `-expandproperty`.  Can you include the code?  Example `@(get-vm | select -ExpandProperty networkadapters ) | Select-Object vmname,vmid, name, id`

Comment: @TravisEz13 [I updated my original post] Right, your example works because it's just getting information about the networkadapters. I'm looking to have networkadapters as a nested item inside the vm object. Here's an example of code that errors: 

get-vm -ComputerName SE124321 | select name, id, state -ExpandProperty networkadapters

Comment: This doesn't attempt to return  "networkadapters as a nested item inside the vm object" thus the error.  NetworkAdapters has some of the same properties of the VM object and when you tell select-object to flatten them together using `ExpandProperty' there is a conflict.  
Get-VM by default returns what you say you want.  Can you clarify the question?

Comment: @TravisEz13 That's what I thought. I just wasn't sure how to achieve what I'm looking for. And yes you did describe what i'm looking for. The problem is, though, Get-VM will only get the networkadapters object if there is only one search result returned. If there are multiple, you only get the string "Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.VMNetworkAdapter" as seen in the example I gave in my original question. Hence why I'm looking to expand the object inside the result

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but you should use an inline expression to solve this.

```
get-vm -ComputerName AB124322 | select @{n="name1";e={$_.name}}, id, state -ExpandProperty networkadapters
```